# How do I initialize this array of arrays within a struct?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to learn rust from the tutorial. I thought Conway's game of life would be a good place to start.

I'm having trouble understanding how to write this Grid::new() fn.

Here's what I have so far:

```
enum Cell {
    alive, dead
}
impl Cell {
    fn new() -> Cell {
        alive
    }
struct Grid {
    priv inner: [ [Cell, .. GRID_SIZE], .. GRID_SIZE],
}

impl Grid {
    fn new() {
        Grid { inner: ???? }
    }
}
```

...

```
fn main () {
    let grid = Grid::new(); // Stack allocated grid (internal stack allocad array)
}
```

What I want is for the grid to be initialized with cells all of the value 'alive'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Grid::new` should initialize `Grid::inner` with a nested fixed-size array literal, which is written just like the type, but with the value you want to initialize your array with in place of the `Cell` type:

```
impl Grid {
    fn new -> Grid {
        Grid { inner: [[alive, ..GRID_SIZE], ..GRID_SIZE] }
    }
}
```

(You can use `Cell::new()` instead of `alive` if you'd rather use the constructor function.)

The `inner` member can then be used in expressions as follows (note that `priv` only controls visibility to code outside the current module):

```
let grid = Grid::new();
let nested_fixed_sized_array: [[Cell, ..GRID_SIZE], ..GRID_SIZE] = grid.inner;
let fixed_sized_array: [Cell, ..GRID_SIZE] = grid.inner[0];
let cell_element: Cell = grid.inner[0][0];
```

In Rust, nested arrays, as used in this example, are a special case of fixed-size arrays.
To see how this works, see the tutorial section on [Vectors and Strings](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/tutorial.html#vectors-and-strings). In particular, unlike vectors (of type `~[T]`), which are dynamically allocated on the heap and can change their length (if they're mutable), fixed-size arrays have their length embedded in the type (`[T, ..LENGTH]`), so that they can't change size after being created. `T` itself must be either a fixed-size type or a pointer. In exchange, however, fixed-size arrays are value types that can be directly allocated on the stack, embedded in `struct` definitions (like `Grid`), etc.

Since a fixed-size array is itself a fixed-size type, a nested fixed-size array is just a special case where a fixed-size array is the element type of a fixed-size array. In particular, the memory taken up by `Grid::inner` is exactly `GRID_SIZE * GRID_SIZE * sizeof(Cell)` (if we ignore alignment). Also useful is a vector of fixed-size arrays `~[T, ..LENGTH]`, when you know the number of columns in a matrix but not the number of rows.

Both vectors and fixed-size arrays can serve as a function argument if the argument is a slice (type `&[T]`).

Some details may change between now and the release of Rust 1.0. If you're curious, searching the [Rust subreddit](http://reddit.com/r/rust) for "dynamically sized types" should turn up the proposed changes and the reasoning behind them, or you can always ask around on Reddit or the #rust IRC channel.

Comment: Thanks! Quick q while I attempt to digest this, is having to declare the array size twice, once in the declaration, and once in the constructor (::new()) methods normal?

struct Grid {
    inner: [ [Cell, .. GRID_SIZE], .. GRID_SIZE],
}

impl Grid {
  fn new() -> Grid { inner: [[alive, .. GRID_SIZE], .. GRID_SIZE] }
}

Comment: Yes, that's how you have to do it. The array size is explicitly part of the type for fixed-size array, so you have to specify it in the declaration of Grid. You then produce a fixed-size array value with [[alive, ..GRID_SIZE], ..GRID_SIZE], where the repeat count ..GRID_SIZE specifies how many elements are there. (In addition, an array literal by itself has type [T, ..LENGTH]. For example, [1, 1, 1] == [1, ..3], and [1, 1, 1] has type [int, ..3]).

Comment: Ok, cool. Since the type contains the length, it makes sense that it must be repeated at both declaration and instantiation. Thanks!