# How to perform efficient vector initialization in Rust?

Tags: arrays, performance, rust, unsafe

What's a good way to fill in a vector of structs in Rust where:

- The size is dynamic, but known at the time of initialization.
- Doesn't first initialize the memory to a dummy value.
- Doesn't re-allocate memory as its filled.
- In this example, all members of the vector are *always* initialized.
  *(In keeping with Rusts assurance of no undefined behavior).*

And ideally

- Doesn't index check each index access
  *(since the size is known when declaring the vector this should be possible).*
- Doesn't require `unsafe`
  *(Not sure if this is reasonable, however the compiler _could_ detect that all values are always filled, allowing such logic in an unsafe block).*

The C equivalent is:

```
struct MyStruct *create_mystruct(const uint n) {
    struct MyStruct *vector = malloc(sizeof(*vector) * n);
    for (uint i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        /* any kind of initialization */
        initialize_mystruct(&vector[i], i);
    }
    return vector;
}
```

I'm porting over some C code which fills an array in a simple loop, so I was wondering if there was a *Rustic* way to perform such a common task with zero or at least minimal overhead?

If there are typically some extra checks needed for the Rust version of this code, what's the nearest equivalent?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/20734743/155423, http://stackoverflow.com/q/27062874/155423, http://stackoverflow.com/q/27393166/155423, http://stackoverflow.com/q/28656387/155423, http://stackoverflow.com/q/29530011/155423, http://stackoverflow.com/q/31360993/155423.

Comment: Checked all the other questions, don't think they're direct duplicates (though some are close).

Answer (score 11):

Just use `map` and `collect`.

```
struct MyStruct(usize);

fn create_mystructs(n: usize) -> Vec<MyStruct> {
    (0..n).map(MyStruct).collect()
}
```

"Initializing" doesn't make sense in safe Rust because you'd need to have the ability to access the uninitialized values, which is unsafe. The [`Iterator::size_hint`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.size_hint) method can be used when collecting into a container to ensure that a minimum number of allocations is made.

Basically, I'd trust that the optimizer will do the right thing here. If it doesn't, I'd believe that it eventually will.

Comment: How would the `initialize_mystruct` fit in here? Also, I assume Rust is smart enough to detect that the iterator has a fixed size and not resize the vector while running collect?

Comment: @ideasman42 You'd use `MyStruct`'s constructor instead of `initialize_mystruct`, and then do `.map(MyStruct::new)`. Rust knows that `map` preserves the length and will allocate properly, yes.

Comment: And since I used a *tuple struct*, `MyStruct's` constructor is just `MyStruct`, the function called in the `map`.